# Recognizing unknown mouse buttons

Tags: c++, windows

So I've been writing a simple Windows program, and it really irks me how in some other programs, they can't recognize the full range of input. For example, in Starcraft 2, you can't bind the extra two mouse buttons on a five-button mouse. For keyboard input, I've been using the WPARAM of the WM_KEYDOWN message, so that if it's unrecognized, I can still recognize it later, even if not display it in a usable form. But for mouse buttons, I've come a cropper, because they have their own messages. So if in the future, I get a seven-button mouse, how can I recognize the sixth and seventh buttons without having to re-write my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a generic "WM_BUTTONDOWN" message available.

The best way to check that out is to use Spy++ on a window. You'll see that there is no generic message sent out. Plus the actual values of all the WM_xxBUTTONDOWN do not follow any pattern either.

What I would do is configure the app to be able to understand 6 new messages entered manually or configured somewhere, for WM_[Z]BUTTONDOWN, WM_[Z]BUTTONUP and WM_[Z]BUTTONDBLCLK, plus all the corresponding WM_NCxxx  messages, because luckily (sort of...), all existing messages more or less share the same wParam + lParam pattern.